# Catch and handle (differently) different exceptions for the same block, with an ensure

Tags: exception, pharo

I know from [the MOOC documentation](http://rmod-pharo-mooc.lille.inria.fr/MOOC/Slides/Week5/C019-W5S04-Exceptions.pdf) that it's possible to have the same handler for multiple exceptions that can occur during some block, e.g.:

```
[ do some work ]
on: ZeroDivide, Warning
do: [ :ex | what you want ]
```

In the same document, there's an example with `ensure` to make sure code is always executed (despite any exceptions):

```
[ doSomething ] ensure: [ alwaysExecuteThis ]
```

However, I would like something like:

```
[ do some work ]
on: ZeroDivide
do: [ :zeroDivide | handle it ]
on: Warning
do: [ :warning | handle it ]
ensure: [ alwaysExecuteThis ]
```

Admittedly, this is my Java experience influencing how I want to use Pharo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems it's possible](http://forum.world.st/How-to-catch-and-handle-multiple-exceptions-tp5098000p5098001.html) using nested blocks:

```
[ [ [ [ doSomething here ]
    on: ZeroDivide
    do: [ :zeroEx | 'zeroExc' crLog ] ]
    on: Warning
    do: [ :warning | 'warning' crLog ] ]
    ensure: [ 'ensure' crLog ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this method to `BlockClosure`:

```
on: exception1
do: block1
on: exception2
do: block2
  ^self on: exception1 , exception2 do: [:ex |
    (exception1 handles: ex)
      ifTrue: [block1 value: ex]
      ifFalse: [block2 value: ex]]
```

Note that `exception1` and `exception2` can be subclasses of `Exception` or instances of `ExceptionSet` (created with `#,`).